# How to access c++ object methods from inside vector with SWIG Python

Tags: python, c++, vector, swig, stdvector

I have two C++ classes:  Foo and Bar.  The constructor for Foo looks like this:

```
Foo(std::vector<Bar *> * bars);
```

The constructor for Bar and one of its member functions are the following:

```
Bar(int data)
int getData()
```

In my interface file I have:

```
%module mySwig
%{
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"
#include <vector>
%}

%include "Foo.h"
%include "Bar.h"
%include "std_vector.i"
namespace std {
    %template(VectorOfBars) vector<Bar *>;
}
```

So then in python I do the following:

```
import mySwig
myBar = mySwig.Bar(5)
```

And now I need to create a `std::vector<Bar *> *` object to pass into the Foo constructor, so I try the following:

```
vector = mySwig.VectorOfBars()
vector.push_back(myBar)
```

To test if this was successful I try:

```
print vector
print vector[0]
print vector[0].getData()
```

If the result of the third print out is still "5" then it was successful, but instead I get what I'm assuming is a pointer value instead

```
<mySwig.VectorOfBars; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::vector< Bar *,std::allocator< Bar * > > *' at 0xb6a9c4d0> >
<mySwig.Bar; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::vector< Bar * >::value_type' at 0xb6a9c3b0> >
3069958048
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I create the vector of Bar pointer objects that I need to pass in to make a Foo object?  Why am I getting a pointer value back instead of the actual value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!  The problem was that the type `<mySwig.Bar; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::vector< Bar * >::value_type' at 0xb6a9c3b0> >` translates to a `Bar *` and not a `Bar` object.  Normally SWIG handles pointers for you but in this case it didn't so when I called a method on the `Bar *` object it gave me back bogus data.

In reality this is exactly what I needed to pass to the Foo constructor.  I was just mistaken in thinking that SWIG would automatically dereference the pointer to Bar so that I could access its `data` attribute.  When I changed the template declaration from

```
%template(VectorOfBars) vector<Bar *>;
```

to the line

```
%template(VectorOfBars) vector<Bar>;
```

then I was able to access `data` but then it was incorrect for passing to Foo's constructor.  I had it right all along.